# Компилятор не воспринимает русский язык

Tags: c++

Что делать если компилятор не воспринимает русский язык? Как его настроить по-другому?

Да, вывод русских символов. `setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS")` - в каждую программу это вставлять нужно?

Comment: Что, прямо так и пишет: "Nicht verstehen!"? Какой компилятор, какая система, в чём выражается непонимание?

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов: выучить его язык, нанять переводчика, купить разговорник, использовать автопереводчик типа Prompt. Может, кто-то еще что-нибудь предложит )))

Comment: Сменить компилятор на более понятливый.

Comment: Ну @avp, ситуация в виндах, когда у редактора одна кодовая страница, а у консоли -- другая? Смена компилятора что даст?

Comment: Скорее всего, парень хочет, чтобы программа выводила на консоль кириллицу, а она выводит безумные кракозябры. Тема эта уже много раз обсуждалась.

Comment: Парень, назвавший себя @nataly_5472?

Comment: "Сменить компилятор на более понятливый" - такая же шутка, как и предыдущий комментарий.

Кстати,  в каждой шутке есть доля шутки. Это если библиотеки считать частью компилятора.

Comment: @alexlz, в наше время все возможно...

Comment: Может автор имеет ввиду вывод русских символов?

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS")

Comment: А помогает?

       setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS")

В принципе это должно быть в переменных окружения `set LC_ALL=RUS`, но если нет, или Вы не уверены, то... Извините, девушка, но это -- винды.

Comment: Да, писать в каждой программе. А ты хочешь в одной написать, а остальные чтобы с ней телепатически связались и сами сменили?

Answer (score 3):

Локаль меняется для приложения.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");
    std::cout << "Привет, Локаль!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << locale << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```